# Incorrect Solution When Squaring Gekko Integer Variables

Tags: python, gekko

If I initialize a boolean variable as 0 I get an incorrect solution (0). If I initialize it as 1 I get the correct solution (1).

```
# Squaring doesn't work
#######################################################

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

b = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True, value=0)

m.Maximize(b**2)


m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(debug=0, disp=True)
```

Returns:

```
Successful solution
Objective:  0.
```

with `b: [0]`

This is a follow up to a previous question ([Gekko returning incorrect successful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271411/gekko-returning-incorrect-successful-solution)) that concerns a model involving matrix multiplication of two gekko arrays with gekko integer variables. I believe I've traced that issue to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```python
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
b = m.Var(value=0, integer=True)
m.Equation(b>=0)
m.Equation(b<=1)
m.Maximize(b**2)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=False)
print(b.value)
```

Output:

```
[1.0]
```

See a demo in [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q1Nh7ZVp5gelYXbumZ4zKPMJ2M0ccf4-?usp=sharing).

In the [gekko examples](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) I saw that `Obj()` (which minimizes) is used along with `Equation()`, so I thought, well maybe the lower and upper bounds of the variable could be expressed as equations instead. Apparently, it works that way.

Answer (score 2):

The `APOPT` solver is a local minimizer that assumes there is only one local minimum. It is also not checking the second derivative to differentiate between a local minimum and local maximum at `x=0`. Hernán Alarcón gave a potential solution where inequality constraints are also solved. This causes the solver to not just accept the initial guess as a solution but to start a search and realize that there is a better solution. There are at least two other methods to find the correct solution.

**Initialize with x>=1e-3**

Instead of initializing at `x=0`, try initializing `x` at any value that does not meet the [KKT conditions](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KuhnTucker).

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
b = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True, value=1e-3)
m.Maximize(b**2)
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=False)
print(-m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

**Switch Solvers**

This is an integer optimization problem but a Nonlinear Programming (NLP) solver such as `IPOPT` can also solve the problem with `value=0`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
b = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True, value=0)
m.Maximize(b**2)
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve(disp=False)
print(-m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```